# How to get compiler version symbol

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Except for constants `RTLVersion` and `CompilerVersion` is there any way how to get version symbol like `VER320` instead of following code?

```
'VER' + IntToStr(Trunc(CompilerVersion * 10))
```

Comment: May I ask you what for (I can imagine that it could be an output from some component)?

Comment: Something like that, It's for testing purposes due to the transfer from XE6 to the latest version of Delphi and I'm used to this format. It's not important, I was just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer to the question is no. There is no mechanism for code to enumerate conditional symbols.

Your current approach is probably the best you can do, subject to there being no guarantee that future release of the compiler will follow the current `VERxxx` convention.

Of course, you may as well simply report the compiler version directly.